# Marshallian demand for Cobb douglas function

Tags: consumer-theory

would like to just check how one can obtain the Marshallian demand for Cobb Douglas function such as u(x1,x2) = x1^a x2^(1-a) ?

Was attempting the question but got somewhat stuck trying to differentiate the FOC of the above function...

Some have recommended implicit differentiation methodology for Cobb Douglas function differentiation but would it be possible to differentiate and FOC for Cobb douglas without implicit differentiation?

Thank you!

Comment: Please show your work, where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

You have the following utility function $u(x_1,x_2)= (x_1)^a · (x_2)^{1-a}$

On first step you must maximize utility fixed to budget constraint: $m≤p_1·x_1 + p_2·x_2$ which tell you that the expenditure of the consumer is restricted by his money $(m)$. In the long term you could suppose $=$ instead of $≤$, because all money would be expended.

Then, take the Lagrange procedure to optimization:

$\max(u(x_1,x_2))$ fixed to $m≤p_1·x_1 + p_2·x_2$:

$ α = u(x_1,x_2) -λ(m - (p_1·x_1 + p_2·x_2))$

You take the first order derivatives of $α$ on $x_1$, $x_2$ and $λ$, simplify the gradient of $α$ and get:

$UMg(x_1)/p_1 = UMg(x_2)/p_2$ where $UMg(x_i)$ is the marginal utility of the good $x_i$

Then you put $x_i$ or $p_i$ from $UMg(x_1)/p_1 = UMg(x_2)/p_2$ into $m≤p_1·x_1 + p_2·x_2$ and you get the Marshallian demand.

Comment: Tell me if this worked for you, if not I will find other approach.